# Prove that $|f(x)|\leq K(1+|x|)$ if $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ a uniformly continuous function. How can I prove that $$|f(x)|\leq K(1+|x|),$$
for all $x\in\mathbb R$ ?

---

I tried to prove that $x\longmapsto \frac{f(x)}{1+|x|}$ is bounded of $\mathbb R$ : Since $f$ is uniformly continuous, there is $\delta>0$ s.t. $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq 1,$$
when $|x-y|<\delta$. But I can't continue.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Suppose $x>0$. Using the your $\delta$, set $n=\lfloor \frac{x}{\delta}\rfloor $. Then

$$|f(x)-f(0)|\leq |f(0)-f(\delta)|+|f(\delta)+f(2\delta)|+...+|f((n-1)\delta)-f(n\delta)|+|f(n\delta)-f(x)|.$$

Comment: And thus $|f(x)-f(0)|\leq [x/\delta]+1\leq \frac{x}{\delta}+1$ what give $|f(x)|\leq |f(0)|+1+\frac{1}{\delta}x$. Setting $K=\max\{1+|f(0)|,\frac{1}{\delta}\}$ I have my result. Thank you very much. And if $x<0$ ?

Comment: juste consider $n=\lfloor \frac{|x|}{\delta}\rfloor $ instead of $\lfloor \frac{x}{\delta}\rfloor $.

Answer (score 0):

If such $K$ does not exist, then there is $x_N$ s.t.
$$ f(x_N)\geq N(1+|x_N|),\ N\rightarrow \infty$$

Here we can assume that $x_N >0\rightarrow\infty$.

Hence

$$ \frac{f(x_N)-f(0)}{x_N -0} > \frac{N+Nx_N-f(0)}{x_N} > N $$

If $0<t_1<\cdots < t_n=x_N,\ |t_i-t_{i+1}|=\delta$, then $$
\frac{\epsilon }{\delta} \geq \frac{\sum_i\ f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})
}{n\delta } > N $$